# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive - Show Table Column only on Desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, hide, multiple-columns

I'm using DataTables.net + Twitter Bootstrap and the responsive layout, what I'm trying is to hide some columns of the table using the class "visible-desktop" thats shows the columns  only in big sizes but It seems not to work, hides well but if I resize the windows to get a desktop width the columns hidden start showing stacked, seems a CSS display class problem, because inherits the type of display from the parent:

```
.visible-desktop {
    display: inherit!important;
}
```

If I manipulate it to

```
.visible-desktop {
    display: table-cell!important;
}
```

works well... Is there a workaround for this? Or I have to write my own class for table column hiding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found that exists a workaround replacing:

```
visible-desktop
```

by

```
hidden-phone hidden-tablet
```

Hope helps someone!

Comment: It is okay to accept your own answer, indicating that it is correct.

Comment: I must to say this answer is only for Boostrap 2, Boostrap 3 doesn't exists when I asked.

Answer (score 29):

## Version 4

EDIT: Bootstrap 4 removed `hidden` and `visible` classes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/2700718) for updated examples, and/or related [official migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities).

** Old Answer for Bootstrap 3 below **

## Version 3

Available classes for `.visible` and `.hidden`.

> Use a single or combination of the available classes for toggling content across viewport breakpoints.

[image: bootstrap css html visible and hidden class grid]

From Bootstrap section here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Because CSS styles added by those classes allow to set: display, display-block, display-inline. He is asking about "table-cell" and if there is a better way to do that with BS (without adding custom styles).

Comment: Seems Google keeps throwing this thread up in response to questions about `visible`/`hidden` classes in Bootstrap (based on the frequent upvotes the original answer receives).

Comment: FYI The above was removed from version 4 of bootstrap.

Answer (score 11):

On Boostrap 3.0 use `.visibilty-<size>` or `.hidden-<size>` responsive classes as described in the official doc.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes