# Simple modern adaptable data tables?

Tags: css, tablelayout

I need tables that scale to mobile devices.

- CSS only, no JS.
- I want the design to have implicit columns, so large, complex tables
  look neat. When i hacked this together i used colspan and "table" but
  i cant make it scale to mobile screens and, well, if im redoing it i
  might as well use something cleverer people than me designed.
- I dont care if this is implemented with  or .
- I want it to be simple. As in not bloated
- When my mediaquery detect a thin screen i want my "table" to collapse
  into one column only. Its good enough.

I guess my problem is that i have insufficient knowledge of layouts, block, inline, float etcetera.
Ive looked into the 960 system. I like the idea but its bloated and its about pagedesign rather than tabledesign.

Basically, i could hack something together. But im looking for a modus operandi that exists out there. I believe there is a good design in use, i just cant find it. To present a table of data must be a common task, no?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive Grid systems, I'd recommend [Bootstrap from Twitter](http://getbootstrap.com/) - it's one of the most mature frameworks at the moment. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365428/265165) shows how to hide columns for mobile devices. JavaScript is not required.

Comment: Ok, thanx for tip, ill check it out. I looked briefly at it Before posting this question, not sure why i didnt delve further. My basic need is to learn how to make a datatable collapse to one column when my mediaqueries detect a mobile devise. And im happy to use divs to create a datatable if that seems the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive tables (without js) is quite a problematic thing.

You can look through those articles:

- http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/
- http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/
- http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

with a js:

- http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

Comment: Thanx for links. Well, im just as happy using divs. The FUNCTION is that of a datatable. My main problem is i cant make them collapse to one column when my mediaquery detect a thin screen. I can probably wing a 12 column implicit layout but would prefer the wisdom of others.