# Hide Table Columns using Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I know that Bootstrap 4 uses [new display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) to show or hide information based on the screen size. My question is how to make these work with a table? I want to remove columns as the screen size is smaller.

I have used "d-xs-none" and it does not have any effect. However, when I use "d-sm-none" the column is removed when the size is 'sm' or larger (the exact opposite of what I need). If I try "d-none d-xs-none" the column never shows up. As in:        `<th class="text-center d-none d-xs-none" scope="col">Location</th>`

Basically, can you show me an example of hiding a table column when resizing the browser to a mobile device? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try using [`d-none d-sm-table-cell`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) for table columns. Colums having these classes won't be shown on xs.

Comment: Worked! Not sure how I missed trying this but thank you!

Comment: I have added to <th> this class (older bootstrap) and column vanished: <th class="hidden">. Just adding hidden property was not enough on older bootstrap. Hopefully this helps someone out there :-)

Comment: This needed to go in both the header columns and the subsequent body td tags to work for me. Thanks!